# Recommended way to approach computed field using I/O operations

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a deeply nested model which on several levels uses this model for an object stored in an S3 bucket:

```py
class S3Object(BaseModel):
    bucket: str
    key: str
```

During serialization I would like to create a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) for each object. I was thinking about simply enhancing the S3 object model using a [computed field](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.computed_field) like this:

```py
class S3Object(BaseModel):
    bucket: str
    key: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def url(self) -> str:
        # I would actually use a global client.
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
        return = s3.generate_presigned_url(
            "get_object",
            Params={"Bucket": self.bucket, "Key": self.key},
            ExpiresIn=3600
        )
```

I'm convinced that this would work quite well, but I've found [this issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1227) that generally discourages from using I/O operations during validation. I'm not exactly sure, though, if this also extends to the computed fields which are on the serialization side. And if yes, what would be another way to achieve the goal.

What I would like to avoid in the first place is to think about the structure of the parent model and to generate pre-signed URLs for all the deeply nested S3 objects after dumping the parent model. If the computed fields approach is really not appropriate, maybe there would be a way to traverse the data and act only on the S3 objects?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try to answer my own question. After much searching and realizing that I only care about the serialization, I came to this approach which in my eyes is quite reasonable and flexible.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from contextvars import ContextVar
from typing import Any, Callable, Literal, Self
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_serializer

_s3 = None

def _get_s3_client():
    global _s3
    if _s3 is None:
        import boto3

        _s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    return _s3

_generate_presigned_urls: ContextVar[
    dict[Literal["expiration"], int] | None
] = ContextVar("generate_presigned_urls", default=None)

@contextmanager
def generate_presigned_urls(expiration: int):
    """Serialize S3Object models to a presigned URL with given expiration."""
    token = _generate_presigned_urls.set({"expiration": expiration})
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        _generate_presigned_urls.reset(token)

class S3Object(BaseModel):
    """Object stored in an S3 bucket."""

    bucket: str
    key: str

    @model_serializer(mode="wrap")
    def _serialize(
        self, serializer: Callable[[Self], dict[str, Any]]
    ) -> dict[str, Any] | str | None:
        if params := _generate_presigned_urls.get():
            try:
                s3 = _get_s3_client()
                return s3.generate_presigned_url(
                    "get_object",
                    Params={"Bucket": self.bucket, "Key": self.key},
                    ExpiresIn=params["expiration"],
                )
            except Exception:
                return None
        else:
            return serializer(self)
```

Now wherever I want to serialize a `Model` with deeply nested `S3Object` models, I simply do this:

```
model = Model.model_validate(input_data)
with generate_presigned_urls(expiration=3600):
    serialized_data = model.model_dump(mode="json", exclude_unset=True)
```

Here are some references I used:

- https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#validation-context
- https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#custom-serializers
- https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1170
- https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1549